# Complex command execution in Makefile

Tags: gnu-make, makefile, multiple-makefiles

I have a query regarding the execution of a complex command in the makefile of the current system.

I am currently using shell command in the makefile to execute the command. However my command fails as it is a combination of a many commands and execution collects a huge amount of data. The makefile content is something like this:

```
variable=$(shell ls -lart | grep name | cut -d/ -f2- )
```

However the `make` execution fails with execvp failure, since the file listing is huge and I need to parse all of them.

Please suggest me any ways to overcome this issue. Basically I would like to execute a complex command and assign that output to a makefile variable which I want to use later in the program.

Comment: Post the full error message after `execvp` which indicates the cause/reason of the error. Make would usually not have any trouble with listing of files however huge it is because, your command merely pipes the output to `grep` and then to `cut`. I suspect that it is some command's execution which returns an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. The error is as below..
make
make: execvp: /bin/bash: Argument list too long
make: *** [all] Error 127
bash >!v

Comment: 1) does the makefile work when you give it a *small* list, perhaps 3 files? 2) Does Make fail at the assignment of `variable`, or when it tries to use `variable`? 3) How do you use `variable`?

Comment: Hi,
The make file just exits after the assignment...to avoid the recursive execution i have made a modification to use := instead of =.... I am planning to use the result of the variable in various succeeding lines of the program.

Comment: Can you *show us* how you use `variable`?

Comment: something like.. mkdir -p $variable in the makefile...

Also i have a clearcase command lsview. which i need to execute with shell.. but for some reason when i execute this command ...

it executes "ls" command along with "lsview" which is a clearcase command.. how do i need to restrict .. to ensure that it does not execute ls command....and only lsview...

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems like you're trying to copy part of a folder structure, which would be a different problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

(This may take a few iterations.)

This looks like a limitation of the architecture, not a Make limitation. There are several ways to address it, but you must show us how you use `variable`, otherwise even if you succeed in constructing it, you might not be able to use it as you intend. Please show us the **exact** operations you intend to perform on `variable`.

For now I suggest you do a couple of experiments and tell us the results. First, try the assignment with a short list of files (e.g. three) to verify that the assignment does what you intend. Second, in the directory with many files, try:

```
variable=$(shell ls -lart | grep name)
```

to see whether the problem is in `grep` or `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than store the list of files in a variable you can easily use shell functionality to get the same result. It's a bit odd that you're flattening a recursive `ls` to only get the leaves, and then running `mkdir -p` which is really only useful if the parent directory doesn't exist, but if you know which depths you want to (for example the current directory and all subdirectories one level down) you can do something like this:

```
directories:
        for path in ./*name* ./*/*name*; do \
                mkdir "/some/path/$(basename "$path")" || exit 1; \
        done
```

or [even](http://thehacklist.blogspot.ch/2011/08/bash-copy-directory-structure-without.html)

```
find . -name '*name*' -exec mkdir "/some/path/$(basename {})" \;
```